# The script activates only the main menu items. How to make the code apply to sub-items

Tags: javascript, jquery

The script activates only the main menu **items**. How to make the code apply to **sub-items**. *2.1* - *2.2* And other subparagraphs if they exist. I can’t understand how to select all **li** elements including those embedded in each other.

Please help me finish the code, or maybe someone has a similar script with the same functionality.

```js
var lastId,
  topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
  topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() + 15,
  // All list items
  menuItems = topMenu.find(".scroll-to"),
  // Anchors corresponding to menu items
  scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
    var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
    if (item.length) {
      return item;
    }
  });

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // Get container scroll position
  var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight;

  // Get id of current scroll item
  var cur = scrollItems.map(function() {
    if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
      return this;
  });
  // Get the id of the current element
  cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
  var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

  if (lastId !== id) {
    lastId = id;
    // Set/remove active class
    menuItems
      .parent().removeClass("active")
      .end().filter("[href='#" + id + "']").parent().addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 6000px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}

#top-menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
}

#top-menu li {
    float: left;
}

#top-menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 25px 7px 25px;
    width: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: .5s all ease-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s all ease-out;
    transition: .5s all ease-out;
    border-top: 3px solid white;
    color: #aaa;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#top-menu a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

#top-menu li.active > a {
    border-top: 3px solid #333;
    color: #333;
}

#zod{
    height:400px;
}

#foo{
    height:400px;
}
#foo2.1{
    height:400px;
    display:block
}
#foo2.2{
    height:400px;
     display:block
}
#bar {
    height:400px;
}

#baz {
    height:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="top-menu">
  <li>
    <a class="scroll-to" href="#zod">zod</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="scroll-to" href="#foo">Foo</a>
      <ul class="articleSubList">
        <li><a class="scroll-to" href="#foo2.1">foo 1.1</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll-to" href="#foo2.2">foo 2.2</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="scroll-to" href="#bar">Bar</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="scroll-to" href="#baz">Baz</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="zod">Zod</div>
<div id="foo">Foo111</div>
<div id="foo2.1">Foo 1.1</div>
<div id="foo2.2">Foo 1.2</div>
<div id="bar">Bar</div>
<div id="baz">Baz</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Because your ID has a `.` in it, which `$($(this).attr("href"))` becomes `$("#foo1.2")` which is `$(".2#foo1")` or `$("#foo1").filter(".2")`.  Change the `.` in the IDs to `_` and it works more or less fine.

Comment: You can’t even imagine how grateful I am to you friend! Thank you very much.